# Difference between $\mathrm {d} x$ and $\delta x $

Tags: notation, nonstandard-analysis

Are $\mathrm {d} x $ and $\delta x $ the same mathematical object from the point of view of the nonstandard analysis?

Comment: please, add some extra information about how $dx$ and $\delta x$ are formally defined. This can improve the quality of your question... and you'll obtain quality responses!

Comment: $\mathrm {d} x $ is as formally defined in the nonstandard analysis,  and the question is essentially about $\delta x $.

Comment: how $\delta x$ is defined? Is it defined as $\delta x = x(t + \tau) - x(t)$ with $\tau \rightarrow 0$? or some else?

Comment: Are you talking about calculus symbols? Because $\delta x$ looks a lot like $\partial x$, which is a partial version of $dx$, meaning "partially differentiated/integrated with with respect to $x$".

Comment: I'm not talking about partial derivatives, I'm talking about this $\delta x $ thing that is thrown around in many physics textbooks. @the_candyman, that _is my question_.

Comment: Which nonstandard analysis sources are you using, user132181?  There are lots of approaches to NSA so the symbols can mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

I will interpret the question as relating not to little-delta but rather to capital-delta.  The notation $\Delta x$ is used in [Keisler's textbook](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html) to denote an infinitesimal increment of the independent variable $x$.  If $y=f(x)$, one also defines the change of the dependent variable $\Delta y=f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$. The ratio $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$, rounded off to the nearest real, gives the derivative $f'(x)$.  To write the derivative in Leibniz's differential notation as the ratio $\frac{dy}{dx}$, one sets $dx=\Delta x$ and $dy=f'(x)dx$.  Then the product rule can be expressed by $d(uv)=udv+vdu$, etc. For additional details see Keisler.

As far as little-delta is concerned, the notation $\delta x$ is often used in the calculus of variations. If you are interested in hyperreal formalisations of related theories in physics you might be interested in consulting the volume by Albeverio et al:

Albeverio, Sergio; Høegh-Krohn, Raphael; Fenstad, Jens Erik; Lindstrøm, Tom. Nonstandard methods in stochastic analysis and mathematical physics. Pure and Applied Mathematics, 122. Academic Press, Inc., Orlando, FL, 1986.